# "Socket is not connected" using grpc in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

After connecting with socket getting like that:

```
[2436:81259] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C1.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR 
[54: Connection reset by peer]
2020-03-17 12:08:01.473638+0530 [2436:81259] [] nw_read_request_report 
[C1] Receive failed with error "Socket is not connected"
nil
```

debug data:

```
debug: duration_ms=40443 request_id=C9D0AECA-A5C1-49C0-A67B- 
ED391AED783B status_code=14 rpc call finished
2020-03-17T12:08:41+0530 debug: duration_ms=40449 request_id=818AD8FF- 
8B98-41F4-BFF4-C5F67581E7E0 status_code=14 rpc call finished
2020-03-17T12:08:41+0530 debug: request_id=FC28704C-82AF-404C-87A1- 
896ADDC46E20 status_code=14 duration_ms=40441 rpc call finished
2020-03-17T12:08:41+0530 debug: connection_id=F2C25657-E82B-4685-AE32- 
C202F119C882 client connection shutdown successfully
```

Comment: Hi can you explain, how you are configuring your sokcet?

Comment: I am using bidirectional grpc  let configuration = ClientConnection.Configuration(target: .hostAndPort(baseUrl, port), eventLoopGroup: group)
        
        
        
        
        let connection = ClientConnection(configuration: configuration)
        let client = appbidrctnlinfsrvServiceClient(connection: connection)

Comment: i think you should use "pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift'" for yourself.